# How to import type from "export module" block?

Tags: typescript

I have the following buried in a Node package:

```js
export module values {

  ...

  export type Document<T = object> = {
    ref: Ref
    ts: number
    data: T
  }

  ...

}
```

I need to import Document. I have tried:

```js
import {values} from "package";

const { Document } = values;

// AND
import {Document} from "package/src/values";
```

How can I import a type from a `export module` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document` is a type, so `const { Document } = values;` could never work (`const` is used to declare variables at runtime, whereas `type`s are only used by TypeScript at compile-time, two different beasts). Additionally, importing from `"package/src/values"` would only work if *values* was a real file.

You were on the right track with `import {values} from "package";`, but you cannot destruct a module to grab a type. Instead, do one of the following:

```
import { values } from "package";

// Option 1: fully qualify Document when using that type
const foo: values.Document = { ... };

// Option 2: create a type alias for Document
type Document = values.Document;
const bar: Document = { ... };
```